# How to create List<string> from a string by replacing the character with range of numbers in better way

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

Input string: "Hello_World_{0}"

I need to create a string list which is like Hello_World_1,Hello_World_2,Hello_World_3,etc... to the given input range.

I have tried below approach, it's working fine.

```
string input = "Hello_World_{0}";
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
foreach (int value in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
  lst.Add(string.Format(input,value));
}
```

Can I achieve the same in one liner using linq?

Comment: Yes. Range + Select + ToList

Comment: @PawełŁukasik can you please rewrite the code ? I'm new to linq. TIA

Comment: `var lst = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i=>$"Hello_World_{i}").ToList();`

Comment: What is wrong with this code, which already works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select -> Fetches each item from the range of 1 -10.
Input string is replaced with each item and creates a list of strings.
ToList -> converts this into list.

```
string input = "Hello_World_{0}";
List<string> lst = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(item => string.Format(input ,item)).ToList();
```

Comment: you don't need to create the list - `.ToList` will do that.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.